# How to remove title bar from the android activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can someone please help me with the issue.I want my activity as full screen and  want to remove title from the screen.I have tried several ways but not able to remove it.

Activity Code :

```
public class welcomepage extends Activity {
    private Button btn;
    EditText userName,passWord;
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    Context ctx =this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcomepage);
   }
}
```

And Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/pic1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.edkul.vimal.edkul.welcomepage">

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to remove the title bar displayed in blue color .Please find the image for the reference :

[image]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".welcomepage"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the activity to Full screen? If you don't want to write the code as suggested in the answer below, create new activity and select Full Screen from the options

Comment: @vimal change the theme style to `<android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">` if u use support library change the them style to `@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` Just add it to your `application` tag to apply it **app-wide** in the manifest.xml

Comment: @Kathi It worked Thanks.But My activity is not full screen.Only title bar goes off.

Comment: you mean i dnt need `status bar` also right ? I dnt get what is full screen in you point ?

Comment: @Kathi There is some gap available between status bar and main screen after removing the title.It should be there or any way we can fill this gap.I am very new to android so Don;t know much .

Comment: can you post image of that?

Comment: @Kathi I have updated the image.There is some gap in black.It will be there  or can we remove this?

Comment: yes can you remove these lines `android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"` in your main_activity.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107415/discussion-between-vimal-mishra-and-kathi).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this:

***this.getSupportActionBar().hide();***

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try
    {
        this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){}

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: Checking the pointer would be better than catching the exception.

Answer (score 172):

you just add this style in your `style.xml` file which is in your values folder

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

After that set this [style](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html) to your activity class in your [AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

**Edit:-** If you are going with programmatic way to hide ActionBar then use below code in your activity `onCreate()` method.

```
if(getSupportedActionbar()!=null)    
     this.getSupportedActionBar().hide();
```

and if you want to hide ActionBar from Fragment then

```
getActivity().getSupportedActionBar().hide();
```

**AppCompat v7**:-
Use following theme in your Activities where you don't want actiobBar `Theme.AppComat.NoActionBar` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` or if you want to hide in whole app then set this theme in your `<application... />` in your `AndroidManifest`.

> **In Kotlin:**

add this line of code in your `onCreate()` method or you can use above theme.

```
supportActionBar?.hide()
```

i hope this will help you more.

Comment: Does this remove it from all activities, since it's in the manifest file as opposed to the activities xml file?

Comment: @gabe If you set this theme in Application level and you don't set any other theme to any activity then it remove from all file otherwise its remove only on that particular activity where you set this style in theme

Comment: In Kotlin this entry is enough `supportActionBar?.hide()`

Answer (score 11):

You can try:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar">
```

that works for me

Answer (score 7):

In your Android Manifest file make sure that the activity is using this (or a) theme (that is based on) `@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` 
This removes the ActionBar completely, but won't make your activity fullscreen.
If you want to make your activity fullscreen only use this theme

```
@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

Or you could change

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

to

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This is what I use to get fullscreen at runtime

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
                mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
            }
```

To exit fullscreen I use this

```
mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Thankls for the reply!! I hace updated my code with application.xml.And I have tried your suggestion .But it is not working.Any suggestion!!

Comment: @vimalmishra You need to change AndroidManifest.xml not application.xml.

Comment: I have update my code with android manifest.xml.Now I am able to remove the titlebar.But It is not fullscreen.

Comment: @vimalmishra Sorry, I thought you only wanted the actionbar to be removed. I'll update my answer.

Comment: wont this make the dialogs look old to android v 2 haha or something, they arent material anymore

Answer (score 5):

Add in activity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and add your `style.xml` file  with the following two lines:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: This will hide your Notification label but title bar will remain there

Comment: This is the solution when not using androidx. However, `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` does absolutely nothing in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You just add following lines of code in  style.xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoTitleBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

change apptheme in  AndroidManifest.xml file

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: `.NoTitleBar` is the key, whatever base theme you are inheriting from.

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin you only need this line:

> this.actionBar?.hide()

You may use it before setting your content for example:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

//this line is important
this.actionBar?.hide()

setContent {
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    .
    .
    .
```

You do not need any other changes on `XML`

Answer (score -1):

Add this two line in your style.xml

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```