# hide Toolbar while scrolling

Tags: android

I have `TabLayout` below `Toolbar` and below the `TabLayout` I have *SearchLayout* (CustomView) I need to hide `Toolbar` while scrolling. I tried many ways but it's not happening Is there any solution for the same?

[image]

> **Here is my xml code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_search_screen"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        style="@style/AppTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_90sdp">

    <include layout="@layout/search_layout" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_45sdp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: where is your xml? post xml as well

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236181/how-to-remove-title-bar-from-the-android-activity/36236700#36236700

Answer (score 1):

Just add appropriate scroll flags to `Toolbar`:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

And appropriate behavior to the scrolling view (in your case to `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `ViewPager`):

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Inside viewPager views, it's children must be scrollable, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I have content inside the `ViewPager` but also it not working

Comment: Haven't seen it before: remove `LinearLayout`. Coordinating layout by `CoordinatorLayout`works only for direct children.

Comment: Then how I add search layout view below the `TabLayout`

Comment: add `android:layout_marginTop="{toolbar+action_bar_size}"` to your search bar and and  `android:layout_marginTop="{search_bar_size}"` to `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Comment: I remove `LinearLayout` and add `android:layout_marginTop` to `ViewPager` and to  `search_layout` also Remove `SwipeRefreshLayout` from code but also it's not working...  I updated my xml code please check it

Comment: Check again `scroll_flags` of toolbar and add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to RecyclerView.

Comment: I Check it in many ways I tried with the all Three flags to the `Toolbar` but This time aslo it not work for me