# How to hide App Title bar on MAUI application

Tags: c#, maui, .net-7.0, .net-maui.shell

I've converted my Xamarin.Forms to a Maui application but have some issues in removing the App bar

[App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTROg.png)

How can I remove the App bar ("Yamas Crew") from my page ?

I already tried the tricks from Xamarin.Forms, but they don't seem to be working

- Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"  (removes the navbar below the app bar)
- ContentPage.Title = ""   (hides the navbar below the appbar)

Comment: From the screenshot, you are testing on Android platform, can you provide some screenshots about the app bar effects on other platforms?
I also tried to reproduce your problem with Shell/TabBar, but my demo app will not show the app bar you said, so it would be helpful for me to reproduce the issue if you could share the relevant code snippets, such as your AppShell.xaml and any relevant parts of your Page.xaml files where you set about the app bar.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, check your theme set in `Platform/Android/MainActivity.cs`.

You should see an attribute above the class similar to this

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ...
```

Alternatively, if you set the theme like below, then the TitleBar will come set from Android and will not be overridden in Maui by `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"`. For this case, I would direct you to other examples for removing the title bar in Android: [How to remove title bar from the android activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236181/how-to-remove-title-bar-from-the-android-activity)

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppTheme);
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```